# How to redirect Domain on Amazon AWS to an external link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

We have all of our domains and setup on Amazon AWS. We have created a not so complex kinda static website which is hosted on a Linux machine at a hosting company. Now we have to redirect the domain e.g. example.com and www.example.com to that url which is like temp.example.hostingcompany.com.

How can I redirect example.com and www.example.com to that url so that the user sees our url and the contents on that url are displayed. 
Note: I want to make it work for both http and https. We are using Amazon https certificates.

I know we can host static websites using S3 Buckets on Amazon but its already been hosted somewhere else and I can't change that decision now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate the website to the new domain, than its simply setup the codebase on new server and make appropriate domain changes it will work.

Secondly, If you want to just show the website on the new domain, but internally its still being available on old domain, than you can use any reverse proxy server like nginx, and use the old domain as the backend and your new domain as its front end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have setup a new site on the new URL, I just want my domains on Amazon AWS to link to that new URL. That's all.